# Share Login between different technolog stack within subdomains

Tags: asp.net, ruby, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

I have a main site implemented with ASP.NET MVC4, let's say it is deployed at:

http://www.example.com

There is another application (Q&A site) which I would like to deploy which is implemented with Ruby(external code), let's say it will be deployed at:

http://questions.example.com

At this stage, user login authentication is done at main site(ASP.NET), and I would like to carry this login to the new Q&A site so that user doesn't need to login again.

In a nutshell, how to share login/cookie between different technology stacks within sub-domains?